# Clojure: Can you use Concat with Other Very Complex Functions?

Tags: clojure, evaluation

```
(ns untitled1.core
  (:require [clojure.string :as str]))

(defn nottrue                              ;helper function for below function
 [inp]
 (not (true? inp))
 )

(defn and-simplify 
"function that, for example, takes: (and-simplify '(and true false)) and evaluates it -> false. 
This function works perfectly if called directly from REPL."
  [last]

  (cond
(some false? last) false
(every? true? (rest last)) true
(= 1 (count (filter nottrue (rest last)))) (let [xyz (filter nottrue (rest last))] xyz)
:else (let [xxx (filter nottrue last)] xxx)
) )


(defn concact_function 
"When the user types: (concact_function '(and false true) '(and true true true false)). It should
return -> Concacted Version: (and true true true false)"
  [my_expression original]

   (println "Concacted Version: " (concat (drop-last original) (and-simplify my_expression)))
  )
```

When I input: (concact_function '(and false true) '(and true true true false))

This is returned: Execution error (IllegalArgumentException) at untitled1.core/concact-function (core.clj:26).
Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Boolean
Concacted Version:  (and true true

I did a  little debugging and I found out that the problem lies when I try to concact (and-simplify my-expression). And-simplify works exactly how it is supposed to do when called directly, but does not like concacting for some reason.

(I do not actually need to print it, I simply need to return it for further manipulation. But I print it for the sake of visualization)

Comment: `(some false? last) false` and
`(every? true? (rest last)) true` should be `(some false? last) [false]`
and `(every? true? (rest last)) [true]`

Comment: Interesting. 1.)  Why does it work if calling and-simplify directly, but not when concating?         
                                                                                                                             
 2.) Just curious, not needed for project, but is there a way return true instead of [true] or false instead of [false] if called directly?                
                                                                                                                        
 3.) If I come across problems like this specifically, how would you advise solving them?

Answer (score 0):

`concat` function works with collections, the function `and-simplify` returns a bool only. To fix this you could put your whole cond clause in a vector or a list, or put the return of every cond clause in a vector.

With the following fix:

```clj
    (defn and-simplify 
      "function that, for example, takes: (and-simplify '(and true false)) and evaluates it -> false. 
      This function works perfectly if called directly from REPL."
      [last]
      [(cond
          (some false? last) false
          (every? true? (rest last)) true
          (= 1 (count (filter nottrue (rest last)))) (let [xyz (filter nottrue (rest last))] xyz)
          :else (let [xxx (filter nottrue last)] xxx)
          )])
```

Will return the expected result:
`Concacted Version:  (and true true true false)`